# Can't connect to local attached SQL Server database after publishing vb.net project

Tags: sql, vb.net, connection-string

I have created a vb.net application and I have published the project in my computer. In my project I'm using the connection string as:

```
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=C:\Program Files\AFDB Database\Application Files\Database\CMS_SMS_DB.mdf
```

So, I'm publishing the project to this folder: `C:\Program Files\AFDB Database`

I have got a clickonce application in the folder and it works fine when I click it.

However, the problem comes when I'm copying this folder to another laptop and try to open the application. It says wrong credentials even though it's correct. I have a login Page in the beginning.

Now, when I enter the correct credentials it doesn't work. This is the vb.net code when the user login:

```
Dim tbLogin As New DataTable
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Found = False
    tbLogin = objDAL.FillDataTable_Query("Select * from LoginTable")
    For itr = 0 To tbLogin.Rows.Count - 1
        If tbLogin.Rows(itr)("Username") = TextBox1.Text And tbLogin.Rows(itr)("Password") = TextBox2.Text Then
            MainForm.Show()
            Me.Close()
            Found = True
        End If
    Next itr
    If Found = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Credentials! Please Try Again!")
    End If
```

`objDAL` is an object of a self-defined class which has connection string as member. I suspect that the connection is not getting established. Maybe, problem with connection string. Can anyone please help me? If any further clarification is needed please let me know.

Thank you all.

**Exception Details:** 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException(0x80131904)
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005)

I'm not able to upload picture because of minimum reputation criteria. :(

Comment: what Exception did u got ??

Comment: Is your ClickOnce also "installing" the database file? Is am suspecting your application is looking for a DB and cannot find it.

Comment: Yes, I have manually put the database in the path mentioned in the connection string. So, the DB is there but it can't access it somehow. @BerndLinde 

I haven't handled the exception for this. I'll handle it now and tell you asap.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem. 
One needs to download sqllocaldbclient from windows site. Install it.
Then create a new service call MSQLLocalDB in command prompt. 
Type sqllocaldbclient in cmd and then   Type :
create instancename -s